# Integration to do with work and power, making use of the chain rule

Tags: integration, derivatives, chain-rule

This problem is related to physics, but my problem is mainly due to calculus topics so I thought I would ask here.

There is a practice problem in my mastering physics book for calculus based physics that states: "A 5.0 kg box is attached to one end of a spring with a spring constant of 80 N/m. The other end is anchored to a wall. Initially the box is at rest at the spring's equilibrium position. A rope with a constant tension of 100 N then pulls the box away from the wall. The coefficient of friction between the box and the floor is .30. How much power is being supplied by the hand or motor pulling the rope when the box has moved 50 cm?"

The solution they give has to do with writing out $K_{final} + U_{final} + \Delta E_{thermal} = K_{initial} + U_{intitial} + W_{external}$ . 
Then they plug in all the values known with $W_{external} = Tension * distance$ and $\Delta E_{thermal} = f_{kinetic\;friction} * distance$. They then solve for v to be 3.6 m/s. With this they give $Power = Tension * velocity = 360\;Watts$.

I understand this but I was wondering if it could be done a different way like this:

First write a Force function of distance I got $F(x) = Tension - f_{kinetic\;friction} - F_{spring} = 100N -(5kg)(9.8 \frac{m}{s^2})(.3)-(80 \frac{N}{m})(x) = -80x + 85.3$

Then I integrate with respect to position x to get $\int F(x)dx = Work = W(x) = -40x^2 + 85.3x + C$

Then I take a derivative of work with respect to time using the chain rule. $\frac {dW(x)}{dt} = Power = P(t)= -80x \frac {dx}{dt} + 85.3 \frac {dx}{dt} + 0$

So now I need to find $\frac {dx}{dt}$ which is just velocity. Going back to the force function, since $F=ma$ then $a=\frac {F}{m}$ So $a(x) = \frac {F(x)}{m} = \frac{F(x)}{5} = \frac{-80x + 85.3}{5} = -16x + 17.6$ Then integrate this to get velocity: $\int (-16x + 17.6)dx = v(x) = -8x^2 + 17.6x + c$ Since v initial is 0 I then did $v(0) = 0 = -8(0)^2 + 17.6(0) + c$ so $c = 0$. Now we have $v(x) = -8x^2 + 17.6x = \frac {dx}{dt}$

then plug it back into the Power function $P(t)= -80x(-8x^2 + 17.6x) + 85.3(-8x^2 + 17.6x)$, so $P(t)= 640x^3 - 1408x - 682.4x^2 + 1501.28x$, then $P(t)= 640x^3 - 682.4x^2 + 93.28x$ I plugged in $x = 50 cm = .5 m$ and did not get the right answer. So could anyone tell me if my steps even make sense and are legal? Maybe it was just a simple negative sign or mistyping of numbers in a calculator. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem asks for the work done by the $100$ N pulling force. This force is always $100$ N and does not depend on distance. Thus the total work it has done after the block moves a distance $x$ is $Fx$ where $F$ is a constant $100$ N. From there, your reasoning would lead to $P = Fv$, just like the solution. If you were asked for the total work done by all the forces on the block then it would look more like your answer (though I haven't looked through it closely so I'm not sure it's exactly right in detail).

Comment: Also, I'll add that there's a physics stack exchange. I don't know that this is off topic here, since physics is a tag, but questions like this will probably get answered more quickly there.

Comment: Thank you I did post it there but only one person commented and that was 6 minutes ago and I posted it like 50 mins to 1 hour before posting it here

Comment: Is there anyway you can think of to solve this using functions somewhat similar to how I tried to solve the problem?

Comment: So I checked and the acceleration function should be a(x) = -16x + 17.06 not 17.6, I accidentally typed it like 17.6. Why is it then that I cannot integrate this to get a velocity then plug in .5 m to get the velocity at that point then multiply that by the 100N force? When I plug in .5 meters into my velocity function, v(x) = -8x^2 + 17.06, I get 6.53 m/s. The book stated that v = 3.6 at this point based on the energy equation.

Comment: @Dominick Ahh I missed that part. To get from accel to velocity you need to integrate with respect to $t$ and not $x$, so in particular the move from $a = 17.06-16x$ to $v = 17.06x-16x^2$ is wrong. You can't do that integral explicitly since you don't know the time dependence of $x.$ What you really have is a 2nd order differential equation to solve, which will give you a sinusoidal solution $x(t)$ that you could then differentiate to get the velocity. The nice thing about energy is it does all of this for you.

Comment: I see. Energy working out so well is awesome, and I will not use the method of trying to find equations to solve a problem on a test or something like that, but I think it would be interesting to know that this problem can be solved in a somewhat different way. Is there anyway to do this with equations, or is the way described pretty much the only way to solve this problem?

Comment: I was thinking of a way to change acceleration to be with respect to time, and then the thought of how the conservation of energy formulas are derived came to mind; using the chain rule to change from a function of time to being a function of position and then integrating etc. Like f = m * a = m * (dv(x) / dt) = m * (dv(x) / dx) * dx / dt = v * dv(x) / dx. I understand loosely how its all related, and it is really cool.

Comment: or rather a derivative of v(x) with respect to time to a derivative with respect to position, not a function of... also that last part " = v * dv(x) / dt " I meant to have a m * with it. like m * v * dv(x) / dx

Comment: @Dominick Yes, you seem to be on the right track. If you take your equation $a = f-kx$ and multiply both sides by $v$ before integrating you get $$ \int \frac{dv}{dt} v dt = f\int vdt - k\int x \frac{dx}{dt}dt$$ and using the fact that $\frac{d(v^2)}{dt} = 2v\frac{dv}{dt}$ (and same for $x$) you get $\frac{1}{2}v^2 = fx-\frac{1}{2}kx^2$ which should look familiar.

Comment: I'm sorry I was sort of ignoring you last part about the sinusoidal solution. I  just woke up a bit ago in the middle of the night and decided not to go back to sleep for now, my bad for asking is there anyway to do this with equations. Thank you for your help. I am not so sure I have such skills to do what you are describing with the 2nd order dif equation. I have only taken up to calculus 2 in college.

Comment: @Dominick I would not recommend trying to get that solution (though it isn't that bad). It's just that that is what you would need to do without the energy shortcut. My last comment shows how this is equivalent to multiplying through by an integrating factor before integrating, but you seem to be on that track as far as I can tell if you're looking at the derivation of energy.

Comment: Well my a equation was (100 - fk - kx)/5, but I sortof see what you are doing. What is an integrating factor?

Comment: I am a bit confused with that last part. I see that the derivative of v^2 = 2v *dv/dt and the x as well and how the last equation is similar to how the problem is solved with energy, but how exactly is this related to the integral above? Is the v a constant in the integration part and can be pulled out and the int of dv/dt is just v so shouldn't you just get v^2?

Comment: @Dominick $$ \int \frac{dv}{dt} vdt = \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{d(v^2)}{dt}dt = \frac{1}{2}v^2$$. This is using the product rule in the first step and the fundamental theorem of calculus in the second.

Comment: What is the product rule with integration? I did it out through integration by parts and got the v^2/2 but did not encounter that middle step. Also why did you not integrate v times (a = (100 - fk - kx)/5) instead of v times (a=f−kx)?

Comment: @Dominick The product rule I used was the usual one for derivatives. It was used to write $(dv/dt) v = \frac{1}{2}d(v^2)/dt$. For the second thing, I was just writing $a = 17.06-16x$. $f=17.06,$  $k=16$. Just giving the two constants names.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand. What part of the $$\frac{dv}{dt} vdt$$ is the product rule applied to? I thought you would need something like $$\frac{d( \frac{dv}{dt} v)}{dt}$$ where you take the derivative of $\frac{dv}{dt} v$. Alright now I see regarding the acceleration equation. Also in addition to integration by parts I found that you can also use u-substitution to solve the integral with $u=v$ and $du=\frac{dv}{dt}dt$ which allows for $\int udu  =  \frac{1}{2}u^2$.

Comment: Applying the product rule to $v^2$ gives $\frac{d(v^2)}{dt} = v \frac{dv}{dt} + \frac{dv}{dt}v = 2 v\frac{dv}{dt}$. Integration by parts is derived using the product rule and fundamental theorem of calculus in this exact way.

Comment: I see. I would not have seen this connection or seen it in that way, I guess it just takes a lot of experience with calculus to make the connection as you had. Thank you for all of your help.